# how to wire BC547 LED flashing circuit in EAGLE?

Tags: led, eaglecad, wiring

[image: Circuit schematic]
I'm studying electronics and I'm trying to grasp the usage of EAGLE. I got an assignment where I must first make this schematic and then wire it on a 3cm x 3cm board.
There is a condition where the LEDs and the voltage source must be arranged in a specific way. [image: PCB conditions]

I have no idea how I have to wire it, because if I put R3, R4, T2 and C1 on the same side with the LED2, I can't wire C1 and C2 on the opposite sides. I thought about putting the resistors in the middle but I can't wire all the components through the resistors. It just doesn't work if they have to intersect.
[image: Failed design]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty simple! Just flip R2 around. Then you can put it as "bridge" over the net that is labeled N$4 in your layout. (That's not even necessary, you can just put the trace between T1's first and third pin.)

Exactly the same for R1: use it as a bridge over N$5, i.e. route N$5 under it.

The rest is no problem at all, you just haven't routed it yet.

Board design takes a little practice, so after you solved this, look at it intensely and find all the ways you could have arranged this "nicer" by doing things such as making traces straight, rotating or shifting components, and so on.

For example, your placement of C1 and C2 is pretty inefficient.

EDIT: Since you're asking:

[image: layout] [image: 3D]

Comment: I got it done thanks to your tips. What are some components that I could've placed better? I'm really new to designing PCBs, so I don't know how one should usually place these.

Comment: Put C1 and C2 between T2 and T1. You could then do the "crossover" x by putting the traces between their pins.

Comment: @Underi look at them pretty pictures.